# How to correctly select data in my AJAX code?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table `place` in mysql and I want to get the photo field in the table `trip_half_day` to show my json script.

The table `place` looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gteNj.jpg).

And `trip_half_day` looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhiaQ.png).

I've tried the code below:

```
<?php
    include("connect.php"); 

    $strSQL = "SELECT trip_id, b.photo AS trip1, c.photo AS trip2, d.photo AS trip3, e.photo AS trip4 , a.type
                FROM  trip_half_day a, place b, place c ,place d, place e
                WHERE a.trip1 = b.place_id 
                AND a.trip2 = c.place_id 
                AND a.trip3 = d.place_id 
                AND a.trip4 = e.place_id
    "; 

    $objQuery = mysqli_query($connection,$strSQL);
    $intNumField = mysqli_num_fields($objQuery);
    $resultArray = array();
    while($obResult = mysqli_fetch_array($objQuery))
    {
        $arrCol = array();
        for($i=0;$i<$intNumField;$i++)
        {
            $arrCol[mysqli_fetch_field_direct($objQuery,$i)->name] = $obResult[$i];
        }
        array_push($resultArray,$arrCol);
    }
    mysqli_close($connection);
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
```

and get this:

[image: this result]

But, the result I want is this:

[image: Destination result]

How can I fix it?

Comment: What error are you getting? It's impossible to help you if you don't tell that

Comment: I want  to result this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqGvj.png but now my result http://projecttest.online/TravelGuide/trip_half_day.php , Sorry this first my question.

Comment: Try to avoid using screenshots for textual data. We can't run your screenshots as code, and we can't edit them to make simple fixes.

Comment: What is the selection criteria for your query? I can see that you are getting too few results, and you want more results, but that does not describe what strategy the query needs to take to select the ones you want.

Answer (score 1):

For what I can see, the missing results (id 5,6,7,8) doesn't fulfill the 4 requirements you're asking. You are asking for 4 conditions that "null" or "empty" values doesn't match.

Try:

```
        WHERE ((trip1 = b.place_id) or (isnull(trip1)))
        AND   ((trip2 = c.place_id) or (isnull(trip2)))
        AND   ((trip3 = d.place_id) or (isnull(trip3)))
        AND   ((trip4 = e.place_id) or (isnull(trip4)))
```

...in the case they are nulls. But seeing your table I think maybe `trip1,trip2...` are stored as text? Please check that.

And please also check [JOIN syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html). That will make your code better, cleaner, smaller, faster.

Comment: You're welcome. Did it solve your problem? If you found my answer helpful, please upvote it. :)

Comment: If this solved your problem accept it as answer so others will know what to do when they encounter a similar problem